# Column line break in Windows Forms

Tags: c#

I am using DataGridView component in Windows Forms .Net. How to break line into column? "\n\r" doesn'work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit the column, edit the DefaultCellStyle property and set the WrapMode property to True.  And change the DGV's AutoSizeRowMode to, say, AllCells so that a row automatically grows in height to fit the text.  The text in the column header and the cells will now automatically word-wrap.  You can use "\n" to force an early wrap.